# Using c.str to convert from string to cstring

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I am practicing some work with cstring and string.
Going from string to cstring using `c_str()` I get an incompatible data type compile error.
For example this is the code that gives said error:

```
string str = "StackOverFlow";
char inCstring[20]{};
inCstring = str.c_str();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `char* inCstring;` instead of `char inCstring[20]{};`.

Comment: Do you know what c_str does?

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post it as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays in C or C++.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that str.c_str() returns a const char*, and you are trying to pass it to a char*. Use strcpy to get your expected result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "StackOverFlow";
    char inCstring[20];

    strcpy(inCstring, str.c_str());

    cout << "str: " << str << endl;
    cout << "inCstring: " << inCstring << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just noticed OP figured out the same answer as "Method B". I do not believe anything is wrong regarding "programming style", only to it not being a 'lvalue =' assignment. Method A is lacking because the new cstring is const.

Comment: The problem is that he was trying to assign to an array (`char []` type) , not `char *` .

Comment: @M.M That is true. Yet it should be noted that in the sample code, directly swapping `char inCstring[20];` to `char* inCstring;` causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: And attempting the lines `char* inCstring; inCstring = str.c_str();` produces invalid conversion error by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

So I have figured out two ways to accomplish this. 
First, it is important to remember that you can't assign to a whole array, meaning it is necessary to specify the element of the array to assign to. Attempting to assign a string to char array simply will not work for this reason. 
 That being said, by specifying the element it would be possible to assign a character in a specific element of a char array. 
 Below are two methods that accomplish a string to cstring(string to char array) "conversion". Please see answer by Vincent for complete code. I have found Method B better since I would like to have max size on my character array.

Method A:

```
string str = "StackOverFlow";
const char* inCstring;
inCstring = str.c_str();
```

Method B:

```
string str = "StackOverFlow";
char inCstring[20]{};
```

Then use strcpy

```
strcpy(inCstring, str.c_str());
```